# Store and get django model object in redis

Tags: python, django, redis

I setup Django & Redis project and try to store django model object in Redis. If I use `django.core.cache` as below, card2 is properly set to django object. However, if I use raw redis conenction provided by django_redis, it gets string representation of django model object.

I set both keys as below. How can I use raw redis connection to get card object itself instead of its string repr? I need it because I'd like to use `mget`, `zrange` like methods of redis.py.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django_redis import get_redis_connection

con = get_redis_connection("default")
card = Card.objects.all()[0]

key = "card_" + str(card.id)

con.delete(key)
cache.delete(key)

con.set(key, card)
cache.set(key, card)

card1 = con.get(key)
card2 = cache.get(key)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert your response from redis to your python object manually.

Hint: **use pickle**, 
here are examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219858/how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870772/get-object-from-redis-without-eval)